# Numpy, duplicating data in different order

Tags: python, numpy

I have data for example

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> b = np.array([3, 4, 5, 6])
```

I want to duplicate each item in each vector to the value of the length of the vector. So the results can are

```
>>> a2 = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4])
>>> b2 = np.array([3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Using `np.tile(b, len(b))` can output `b2`. However, how can I get `a2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two replications are a bit different. The first one can be obtained with [**`.repeat(..)`** [numpy-doc]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
>>> a.repeat(len(a))
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4])
```

the second one with [**`.tile(..)`** [numpy-doc]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html#numpy.tile):

```
>>> np.tile(b, len(b))
array([3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do both in one go using `np.meshgrid`

```
A,B = map(np.ravel,np.meshgrid(a,b,indexing='ij'))


A
# array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4])
B
# array([3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```